# Change value of select javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, jquery-events

I need to change the value of a `<select>` to a particular option, using js/ jQuery. Now, that wouldn't be too hard, the only problem I have is that **I also need the `change` event to be dispatched on the select** when I change the value.

Comment: and where is the code??

Answer (score 3):

Should be pretty straight forward

```
$('select').val('value of option').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the `.change()` event on the `select` after changing the value:

```
$('select').val('option value here').change(); // or .trigger('change')
```

Answer (score 1):

As the above says its pretty simple all you have to do is set of the `.change()` event

```
('select').val('value of option').trigger('change');
```

Comment: If above said, then why the same you are saying?

Comment: The more of the around same answer will give him more confidence in that solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Use chaining to:

1. Set the value using [`.val("Something")`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)
2. Trigger the change event using [`.trigger("change")`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) or [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Something like this:

```
$("select").val("So select! Much change").trigger("change");
```

[Read more about triggering event handlers](https://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/)